# How to convert dimensional DB model to datamining friendly layout?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, statistics

My problem is, I have a Dimensional Model DB NFL league. So we have Players, Teams, Leagues as the dimension tables and Match as the factual table relates these tables. For instance, if I need to query stats of a player in a particular match or a range of matches, it is very painstaking SQL query with lots of joins to convert machine readable ID based tables to human readable name based version. In addition, analysis of that data is also very painful. For being a solution, I suggest to transform that DB to Analysis friendly version. Again for example, Player table ll include players at each row with related stats and same for Teams as well.

The question is, is there any framework, method or schema that might guide me to design the analysis friendly DB layout. Also still the use of SQL is favorable or any non-sql DB is better for this problem?

I know it sounds very general question but I just want to hear some expertise about the topic. Therefore, any help, suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Could you show a sample query that you consider painstaking?

Answer (score 1):

I was in a team faced with a similar situation about 13 years ago.  We used a tool called "PowerPlay", a Business Intelligence  tool from Cognos.  This tool was very friendly to the data analysts, with drill down capabilities, and all sorts of name based searching.

If I recall correctly (it's been a while), The BI tool stored the data in its own format (a data cube) but it had its own tool for automatically discovering the structure of an SQL based data source.  That automatic tool was really struggling with the OLTP database, which was SQL (Oracle) and which was a real mess... a terrible relational design.

So what I ended up doing was building a star schema to collect and organize the same data, but more compatible with a multidimensional view of the data.  I then built the ETL stuff to load the star from the OLTP database.  The BI tool cut through the star schema like a hot knife through butter.
And the analysts didn't have to mess with ID fields at all.

It sounds like your starting place is like the star schema I had to build.  So I would suggest that there are BI tools out there that you can lay on top of your star and that will provide precisely the kind of analyst friendly environment you are looking for.  Cognos is only one of many vendors of BI tools.

A few caveats:  If you go this way, you have to make an effort to make sure your name fields "make sense" if they are going to provide meaningful guidance to the analysts trying to drill down or search.  Sometimes original data sources treat name fields as more or less meaningless stuff, where errors don't matter much.  The same goes for column names.  Column names that DBAs like are often gibberish to data analysts.  You may also have to flatten any hierarchical groupings in your dimension tables, but you may have already done this.  It depends on what your BI tool needs.

Hope this helps, even if it's a little generic.

Comment: you pointed the exactly where I am :) Thanks for the dreat explanation. Do you know any open source BI tool ?

Comment: All of the BI tools I'm aware of are kinda pricey.  Other contributors may help in this regard.